# Is "I asked many questions that I had before" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I would like to ask whether this sentence is grammatically correct or not:

> I asked her many questions that I had before.

I think it sounds better if I say "I asked her many questions that I have had before".

Comment: Hi Fumble Fingers, thank you for editing. So which one is correct? "I asked her many questions that I have had before?" or "I asked her many questions that I had before." ?

Comment: Neither. I think you want "I asked her many questions that I had had before."

Comment: PT, answer depends on what you mean to say.  Which, if either, of "I asked many questions that I had asked before" or "I asked her many questions that I had asked her before" do you mean?  By the way, one can fit *have* into sentences like "I asked her many questions that I have often asked", but your mix of "I asked ... I have had" (past tense form and present perfect form) discomfits my ear.

Comment: The student actually wants to write - "she asked her many questions that she always had in her mind." Means, the questions that she has in her mind since before, now is being asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first question we need to ask is this:
Do you mean, "I asked her many questions that I had asked her in the past" or do you mean, "I have had many questions in the past and I asked her these questions now?"

Comment: Thank you Jim, I think she means - "I asked her many questions that I have had in the past". Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: @PartTimer, It depends on how *in the past* is interpreted. If it refers to a period of time that is finished, then the past simple is required. E,g. "*In the past I had many questions about this issue (but now I don't)*". If, on the other hand, you interpret the past as continuing into the present, then the present perfect is acceptable. Three examples from Google: "*I admit it, in the past I have googled myself", "In the past I have composed music inspired by magic squares", "In the past I have only done films where I have played the lead*".

Comment: Shoe, thanks for the explaination. Based on the situation, I guess the correct sentence should be - "I asked her a lot of questions which I had had before."

Comment: Shoe, I want to confirm the following: - 1. Past Simple tense and present perfect tense should not appeared in one sentence. Correct? so that is why my first sentence is wrong because i put Past Simple and Present Perfect together in a sentence. How do you explained : In the past I have composed music inspired by magic squares? You are talking about past right? And I thought present perfect is for 'present tense'? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @PartTimer, The expression "*in the past*" is conceived by the speaker as extending up to the present, hence the present perfect. The implication is that he or she may compose more music of a similar nature in the future The intuitive, sub-conscious tense choices that native speakers make can be extremely subtle.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and answer. It helps a lot really